# Mongoose schema object type issue

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a schema like this -

```
const employerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username:String,
    password:String,
    alias :String,
    employees:{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, default: {} }
})
```

Basically I want each employer to have a list of employees. However,when I try to put data inside the employees object from a form(three details - employeeName,employeeAddress and employeePhone)and like this -

```
app.post('/addNewEmployee',function(req,res){
    const employeeName = req.body.employeeName
    req.user.employees[employeeName] = {
        name: req.body.employeeName,address: req.body.employeeAddress,Phone:req.body.employeePhone
    }
    req.user.save()
})
```

Even after executing this I get nothing. I still have the default empty object in my database under the employer. Where am I going wrong here?

Edit:- I tried using the below logic as well but it still fails to put anything in the object.

```
app.post('/addNewEmployee',function(req,res){
    const employeeName = req.body.employeeName
    Employer.findById(req.user.id,function(err,foundUser){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        else{
            foundUser.employees[employeeName] = {
                name: req.body.employeeName,address: 
                  req.body.employeeAddress,Phone:req.body.employeePhone
            }
            foundUser.save()
        }
})
})
```

Comment: Is this `req.user` a mongoose model on which you are calling `.save()`. If not you should be getting an error like: `req.user.save() is  is not a function`. Its unclear from the code above about the Model on which `.save()` is called

Comment: req.user basically fetches the current logged in user. I tried console logging it and it works as expected. Not sure why save() is not working.

Comment: My question was basically if `req.user` is a [mongoose model](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) defined from a `Schema`? `.save()` is model api method and can only be executed from a mongoose model object not any other.

Comment: I'll edit my question with the part where I did not use req.user.

Comment: Have you tried passing the callback function to `.save()` and seeing if it receives any error object as an argument?